# How do you set up secure files w/ Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

Is this possible with a view coupled w/ storage on S3, has anyone set Wagatil up with django-storages or django-private-storage? I've set up django-cms w/S3 but the private/smedia with django-storages only works for local files/server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you mean, but using S3 as storage provider for Wagtail is explained here: https://wagtail.io/blog/amazon-s3-for-media-files/

Basically:

1. Create an AWS IAM user with the correct permissions
2. Install these packages:

   ```
   pip install django-storages  
   pip install boto3
   ```
3. Add `storages` to your INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`:

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'storages',
   ...
   ]
   ```
4. Add credentials and paths to `settings.py`:

   ```
   AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '####'
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '####'
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '####'
   AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
   MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
   DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
   ```